# Why the conflicting variables?

Tags: javascript, python, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm getting conflicting results between the facebook javascript SDK and the python requesthandler variables. The Javascript SDK says my user is not logged in, which is correct, while my template variable that comes from the base request handler says that my user is logged in and displays the name of the user. Is there enough info to tell what is wrong or should I paste the code I think is relevant here? A link to the login page that has the error is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com/login). The example I used is called the runwithfriends demo app from facebook and everything with that app worked except using the logic from the app just from a website without requiring the user to be in the iframe of the app.

Plus I can't seem to get the real-time API working. I can only save userID and not refresh user data - why? I have the code but I'm not sure what's most relevant but here's some of the request handler, the relevant code is basically exactly the same as the one from the demo app:

```
def render(self, name, **data):
    logging.debug('render')
    """Render a template"""
    if not data:
        logging.debug('no data')
        data = {}
    data[u'js_conf'] = json.dumps({
        u'appId': facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        u'canvasName': facebookconf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME,
        u'userIdOnServer': self.user.id if self.user else None,
    })
    data[u'logged_in_user'] = self.user #variable that is the problem
    data[u'message'] = self.get_message()
    data[u'csrf_token'] = self.csrf_token
    data[u'canvas_name'] = facebookconf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME
    self.response.out.write(template.render(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', name + '.html'),
        data))
```

And even more strange, I can also get the application in a state where the javascript SDK says the user is logged in and the template variable `logged_in_user` says otherwise. Why are the variables conflicting?
Update: Here are screenshots from the strange login flow. I can go to my page and my name from facebook appears:
[image]
Then when I go to next page it also looks alright and has my name
[image]
But if I log out then I gets in impossible state: my name + logged out

[image]
How can I resolve this strange conflict between js and back-end?

Update: Since I only have this problem for one of my apps I can take what works from my other app and integrate. This page seems to work from my other app: http://cyberfaze.appspot.com/file/20985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'user' is probably referring to the Django user not the Facebook user. Make sure you synchronize the two accounts correctly using a custom authentication backend. It's possible that the accounts get out of sync i.e. if the user switches browsers.

Keep in mind that the Facebook Python SDK will stop working after October 1st unless they update it to Oauth2.0 which is unlikely.

I just updated [django-facebook-graph](https://github.com/feinheit/django-facebook-graph) to work with the new authentication flow.

Comment: There is a version of facebook python SDK which has been modified to support OAuth 2.0 on github [here](https://gist.github.com/1190267) - for my use case, I had to tweak it to better handle a timeout error case, but it does work out of the box.